# Table with some columns in percent, the rest fluid

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table, where two columns will receive `30%` of the space each:

```
<td style="width: 30%;">
```

The remaining columns should just equally share the remaining space. How do I accomplish this? Do I just give the remaining columns no `width`at all?

Comment: Hello Sir @Roland,
Just see my Code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bt5nj/335/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, declaring no width would work (see snippet below).

`<td>` automatically adjusts width evenly unless otherwise declared (e.g. `<td style="width: 30%;"></td>`)

**EDIT**

When you put data in the fluid cells, they will adapt to the size of the data inside them. To keep them the same width as each other and wrap the text, you will need to declare a width percentage for the fluid cells.

Since we're already using 60% with the first two cells, we have 40% left. We will need to divide 40 by the number of extra cells to get the percentage value for their width.

Thanks to @Chiller for pointing this out!

```css
table {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  background: red;
  /* Edit - divide number of fluid cells by 40
  (because we're using 60% with the first two)
  in this example the number is just over 13) */
  width: 13%; /* the number we calculated */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 30%;"></td>
    <td style="width: 30%;"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if you add content to remaining tds? My guess is it won't work !

Comment: @Chiller why do you think that? Seems fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/dennispreston/q3k4t7q5/

Comment: In your example you are giving the same content for the cells.. try setting different content for each and you will see the result :)

Comment: @Chiller you're right! Then you'll need to know the number of cells and define a width, in this case `width: 13%`. Well spotted!